# Css z index does not work with position absolute and ul

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the ul above the rest of the content and the z index is not working. 
I added the position property as needed to set z index but still does not work, what i am doing wrong?
How i can fix this?

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.nb-drop-down {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
.nb-drop-down ul {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
}
.nb-drop-down button, .nb-drop-down li {
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.nb-drop-down button {
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  position: relative;
}
.nb-drop-down button::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  right: 15px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-width: 10px 6.5px 0 6.5px;
  border-color: #e3e3e3 transparent transparent transparent;
}
.nb-drop-down button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.nb-drop-down li:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

<div class="nb-drop-down">
  <button class="nb-main-item">Main Item</button>
  <ul class="nb-list">
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li>Item Two</li>
    <li>Item Three</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<h1>hello</h1>
```

Comment: `z-index` is for stacking order, it doesn't 'push' overlapping elements. Why set the `<ul>` as `position: absolute` in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UL` is above `H1` (or everything else in general), but has transparent background. Set background, eg:

```
.nb-drop-down ul {background: white;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5ojk1ojq/

Comment: Now you're simply *hiding* the `<h1>` because it's underneath the `<ul>`.

Comment: @haim770: sure. OP asked for that, aren't they?

Comment: Hard to tell. I read "*above* the rest", not "in front of the rest", but maybe...

Comment: @haim770: regarding the fact this answer was accepted, I found solution. Note that there is a lot people who has English as 2nd (3rd, ...) language and don't see different between `above` and `in front of`. I'm one of them, I understood `above` correctly, or better, as the OP wanted :-)

Comment: +1 For getting the OP's intention. English is not my mother tongue as well, but somehow (when posting the code in Fiddle) I realized he must have wanted the `<h1>` at the bottom.